# Grub does not pick up new kernels (was: How to update Fedora's kernel)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, fedora, updates, kernel

In a seemingly endless quest to get Vagrant working I am trying to update Fedora. Vagrant needs VirtualBox, VirtualBox needs kernel sources, and kernel sources are only available for the latest kernel version.

```
$ uname -r
4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64
```

I tried updating the system.

```
$ sudo dnf update
Last metadata expiration check: 2:03:57 ago on Tue May 10 11:20:17 2016.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Clearly the system is already updated.

```
$ sudo dnf install kernel

Last metadata expiration check: 2:05:00 ago on Tue May 10 11:20:17 2016.
Package kernel-4.4.8-300.fc23.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

I tried removing the current kernel:

$ sudo dnf remove kernel-(uname -r)

Complete. Let's see what's installed:

```
$ rpm -qva "kernel-*"
kernel-core-4.4.8-300.fc23.x86_64
kernel-core-4.4.4-301.fc23.x86_64
kernel-headers-4.4.8-300.fc23.x86_64
kernel-modules-4.4.8-300.fc23.x86_64
kernel-devel-4.4.8-300.fc23.x86_64
kernel-modules-4.4.4-301.fc23.x86_64
```

All good so far.

So I rebooted....

Only to find that three kernels were listed in Grub: 4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64, and two much older ones from the 4.2 branch.

```
$ rpm -qva "kernel-*"
kernel-modules-4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64
kernel-core-4.4.8-300.fc23.x86_64
kernel-core-4.4.4-301.fc23.x86_64
kernel-core-4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64
kernel-headers-4.4.8-300.fc23.x86_64
kernel-modules-4.4.8-300.fc23.x86_64
kernel-devel-4.4.8-300.fc23.x86_64
kernel-modules-4.4.4-301.fc23.x86_64
```

What on earth is going on here?

Edit: I later attempted to update grub to pick up the new kernel.

```
$ cd /boot/grub2
$ mv grub.cfg grub.cfg.old
$ sudo grub2-mkconfig -o grub.cfg.new
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.8-300.fc23.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.4.8-300.fc23.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.4-301.fc23.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.4.4-301.fc23.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-0468365313db460f867aa0a7c6284ace
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-0-rescue-0468365313db460f867aa0a7c6284ace.img
```

I can confirm that the new config file has the correct entries:

```
 $ grep 4.4 grub.cfg
  menuentry 'Fedora (4.4.8-300.fc23.x86_64) 23 (Workstation Edition)' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64-advanced-29e2d74b-255e-44fa-b8e7-edb54b33f225' {
linux16 /vmlinuz-4.4.8-300.fc23.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora_deepwinter-root ro rd.lvm.lv=fedora_deepwinter/root rd.luks.uuid=luks-b09d62d7-9782-42d5-890d-f117ccb8a1cc rd.lvm.lv=fedora_deepwinter/swap rhgb quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012' LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
initrd16 /initramfs-4.4.8-300.fc23.x86_64.img
    menuentry 'Fedora (4.4.4-301.fc23.x86_64) 23 (Workstation Edition)' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64-advanced-29e2d74b-255e-44fa-b8e7-edb54b33f225' {
linux16 /vmlinuz-4.4.4-301.fc23.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora_deepwinter-root ro  rd.lvm.lv=fedora_deepwinter/root rd.luks.uuid=luks-b09d62d7-9782-42d5-890d-f117ccb8a1cc rd.lvm.lv=fedora_deepwinter/swap rhgb quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012' LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
initrd16 /initramfs-4.4.4-301.fc23.x86_64.img
```

Now, I'm not dual-booting or anything complicated like that. I have one hard drive with one Fedora installation on it. How can it be that grub.cfg has the right entries but when I reboot the computer, it still shows 4.2.4, 4.2.3 and 4.3.5? Could it be a mount point problem with multiple /boots?

```
$ mount | grep boot
/dev/sda2 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)

$ ls /dev/ | grep sd
sda
sda1
sda2
sda3
sda4
```

The kernel files are definitely there:

```
$ ls /boot | grep 4.4
config-4.4.4-301.fc23.x86_64
config-4.4.8-300.fc23.x86_64
initramfs-4.4.4-301.fc23.x86_64.img
initramfs-4.4.8-300.fc23.x86_64.img
System.map-4.4.4-301.fc23.x86_64
System.map-4.4.8-300.fc23.x86_64
vmlinuz-4.4.4-301.fc23.x86_64
vmlinuz-4.4.8-300.fc23.x86_64
```

Perhaps I should try reinstalling grub into the hard drive...

```
$ sudo grub2-install --target=/dev/sda
grub2-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/dev/sda/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.
$ sudo grub2-install --directory=/boot
grub2-install: error: /boot/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.
```

I dont know what modinfo.sh is, but it looks important...

At this point I'm not really sure why the Grub is not picking up the kernels or where its loading its from config from.

Comment: probably the grub list didn't get updated for some reason. `update-grub` or something similar might help. If the kernel is installed and not visible in the grub, the problem is there.

Comment: You're right about tht Jakuje and I've updated my answer appropriately.

Comment: Is this an `UEFI` type system or `BIOS` based system? If it is `UEFI` the location will be `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` for the grub2 config based on [Fedora's documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/23/html/Multiboot_Guide/GRUB-configuration.html)

Comment: It should be UEFI. BIOS mode is disabled and $ [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS returns UEFI. Yet /boot/efi is an empty directory. Could it be a broken mount point? At one point I had to clone this installation onto a BIOS based system; I then cloned it back from the BIOS system into this laptop where it was originally installed. If it is a broken mount point, how would I tell? mount | grep -i efi returns
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)

Comment: I had this issue and it was caused by the fact, that the EFI partition was not always mounted during a kernel update so I ended up having to parallel versions of the EFI system and this led to the problem that the grub menu was sometimes not updated. So check the `fstab` options in /etc/fstab.